# pointers to arrays in c not working

Tags: c, pointers

```
char (*ptr)[10];
scanf("%s",ptr);//inputing a string
```

Why is this not working?
According to me this should work because ptr is a pointer to an array of characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pointer to an array is **NOT** an array, you have nowhere to put your characters.

It's like having a doormat without a house, that doesn't mean you have somewhere to receive your guests.

To have the above working you should

```
char ptr[10]; // This is where you have space, specifically stack space
char (*this_is_a_pointer_to_array)[10]; // This only holds space to keep an address to an array
this_is_a_pointer_to_array = &ptr;
scanf("%s",ptr);
```

although you don't really need the pointer to array in the case above.

A pointer to an array only holds as much space as necessary to hold the address to an array, there's no space to store anything else than an address. If you horribly circumvent the typecasting mechanism you might use that space to store some characters instead of an address, but that is against every moral fiber of my body and probably against every typecasting rule as well.

Comment: +1, good explanation, but you mean `this_is_a_pointer_to_array = &ptr;` (note ampersand ;)

Comment: ampersand is not required for arrays,because array itself is an address.

Comment: @user3475381, assignment from incompatible pointer type (without &)

Comment: The ampersand can create some confusion between pointer to char and pointer to an array, I'll add it for clarity's sake since in this case it's the pointer to an array that we wants

Comment: @user3475381 Array itself is an address, right, but pointer to an array is not just an address, rather an address to an address; so you do need `&`, to have the address of the array (address).

Comment: @user3475381, compile with warnings and see ThoAppelsin's comment

Comment: @ThoAppelsin, it is not a pointer to a pointer.  `ptr` is an array that will decay to `char*`, and `this_is_a_pointer_to_array` is a `char(*)[10]`, but after the assignment, if you `printf("%p %p", ptr, this_is_a_pointer_to_array)` you will see they have the same value.

Comment: @AlterMann yes the ampersand is required,i get it now.

Comment: @pat, he say an address to an address (and it is) not a pointer to a pointer

Comment: Ahh, so the first address is the address of the pointer, which is pointing at the second address, which is the array.  I read address to mean pointer.  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

`ptr` is not a pointer to `char` instead it is a pointer to an array of 10 `char`s.